# Querying Shopify JSON data via the API with PowerShell (Error 401 with Invoke-Webrequest)

Tags: json, powershell, shopify

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to use Shopify's API to access JSON data. I've created a private app, and confirmed this works when accessing a JSON feed via a browser. I've also actually gotten this working using System.Net.WebClient, but I'd prefer to work with Invoke-WebRequest but that doesn't authenticate correctly.

When trying:

```
    $uri = "https://apikey:password@anewshop.myshopify.com/admin/products.json"
    $json = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -contentType "application/json" -Method Get -Headers @{"Host"="anewshop.myshopify.com";"Authorization"="Basic"} | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I receive and error 401:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
```

Authentication via PowerShell fails, but with a browser it does not. When making the request in Firefox, the request headers are as followed:

```
Host: "anewshop.myshopify.com"
User-Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"
Accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
Accept-Language: "en-US,en;q=0.5"
Accept-Encoding: "gzip, deflate"
Cookie: "_secure_admin_session_id=35ce7a14ee4f510c2e20d57f66960503; request_method=GET"
Authorization: "Basic StrippedLongString="
Connection: "keep-alive"
Cache-Control: "max-age=0"
```

The working code with System.Net.WebClient is as followed:

```
$uri= "https://anewshop.myshopify.com/admin/products.json"
$apiKey = "apikey"
$password = "password"
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($apikey, $password)
$json = $webclient.DownloadString($fullurl) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Can anyone explain why Invoke-Webrequest fails? What is it missing exactly? Additional headers?

Edit: This also raises an additional question, of how I would actually update data via the API. Usually I'd use Invoke-Webreqest with POST/PUT but I'm not sure how WebClient handles this scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is the URI different for the two methods?  Wouldn't you need to call the same URI as in the WebClient example and put the apikey and password in the header?  I don't know their API so please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: You were right in your suspicion. I had assumed the apikey/pass in the URi would work as it works in a browser (not sure why I drew that conclusion). I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by ensuring the apikey and password were base64 encoded in the headers:

```
$uri = "https://anewshop.myshopify.com/admin/products.json"
$apikey = "apikey"
$password = "password"
$headers = @{"Authorization" = "Basic "+[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($apikey+":"+$password))}
$products = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -contentType "application/json" -Method Get -Headers $headers | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: This worked for me as the above one cut off the result for some reason:

$uri = "https://anewshop.myshopify.com/admin/products.json"
$apikey = "apikey"
$password = "password"
$headers = @{"Authorization" = "Basic "+[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($apikey+":"+$password))}


$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $resource -Header $headers